# Name this Embeddable Schema

Tags: tridion

I'm working with a fairly generic, re-usable embeddable schema.

**I'm stuck on a name for this "basic" schema!**

### "Basic"

Embeddable schema fields:

- Banner (or large) Image as a multimedia link
- Thumbnail Image (maybe, depends if large image is re-usable)
- Headline (single-line text)
- Summary (multi-line text)
- `Body Content` (another embeddable schema, allow repeating)

### Body Content

This should be familiar:

- Body Subheader (single-line text)
- Body Content (mandatory, allow repeating)

**Would a name something related to the organization be appropriate for the "`basic`" embeddable schema?** Maybe this should this either be broken out further or not even combined.

Comment: I am a little confused - Are you looking for a name for the Embedded Schema or the Generic on that embeds it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How's about

> General

Or

> General Content

Answer (score 5):

I suggest **ARTICLE** because HTML5 also use same name for such information and ARTICLE comes in HTML5 from recommendation of web developers across the globe.

Comment: Ah, didn't think of that. It's a difficult call because this somewhat matches, but in this case I'm looking at the name of just _part_ of an HTML 5 Article. Also this embeddable schema definition should be independent of its expected markup, even if it will be HTML 5. Rendering side the component presentations that uses the schema that uses _these schema_ could very likely be wrapped in an `<article>` tag.

Answer (score 3):

Difficult to say which one is better. I think all the answers so far are valid. I would probably go with `Generic Paragraph` only because you are in fact defining some kind of body of content (like a paragraph).

Also `Generic Content` or `Generic` are suitable names.

Comment: Had  interesting discussions on when to actually treat that body content as paragraphs or not. For Q&A, one component but each pair would be its own header/body section. But for long articles, client prefers one long RTF. But again for small sections that could present as tabbed containers or accordions, back to multiple body content sections. Strangely the scenarios make sense.

Answer (score 2):

I feel it should be named as **`Generic`**?

One more thing:-

The fields which are mentioned, they might be used directly or indirectly by either one or more schemas based on requirements.

Comment: Good point, that way the schemas would have the same set of basic fields but have better security and templating options.

Comment: Oh, but it can't be used directly. (Tridion) embeddable schema don't have a namespace and can only be used in other (emeddable or regular) schema.

Answer (score 2):

Headline + Summary + Body I normally call an Article, but your Generic is equally valid. The Banner + Thumbnail make it a bit more specific, so might make the name less correct - although the schema may be equally valid, depending on your use-case.

Comment: I've seen article before, typically great with Marketing as the authors or content-heavy sites. For embeddable schema, I'm surprised you didn't suggest a more dev-friendly "ES_Article" or similar. ;-)

Comment: I had missed the part about wanting it to be embeddable. There's probably better names than Article in that case, so I'll remove my suggestion.